# Define Spring bean with a Map-typed constructor argument

Tags: spring, grails

In my Grails app, I'm trying to define a Spring bean in `resources.groovy` that requires a Map-typed constructor arg. I tried this:

```
Map<Class, String> mapArg = [(String): 'foo']
myBean(MyBeanImpl, mapArg)
```

But I get the error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'myBean': Could not resolve matching
>   constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple
>   parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

The implementation class has a single constructor which is defined thus

```
MyBeanImpl(Map<Class, String> map) {
  // impl omitted 
}
```

My guess is that the problem is caused by the fact that I've defined a constructor that takes a single `Map` arg which has the same signature as the default constructor Groovy adds to every class.

If so, a solution would appear to be to add a factory method such as

```
MyBean getInstance(Map map) {
  // impl omitted  
}
```

But I'm not sure how I can call this to define a bean (in `resources.groovy`) that is constructed from a factory method that requires a parameter.

Comment: That ought to work.  One slight wrinkle is that you need to define the map as `[(String):'foo']` with parentheses in order to use the `Class` object as a map key rather than the string "String", but I don't think generic type parameters are significant in deciding whether or not the constructor matches.

Comment: @IanRoberts in the code itself, I did have brackets around the class for the reasons you state. I've updated my question, well spotted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell the syntax you're using ought to work.  Does the alternative syntax:

```
Map<Class, String> mapArg = [(String): 'foo']
myBean(MyBeanImpl) { bean ->
  bean.constructorArgs = [mapArg]
}
```

work any better in your case?  Failing that, declaring the map as a bean in its own right should definitely do it:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean

classMap(MapFactoryBean) {
  sourceMap = [(String):'foo']
}

myBean(MyBeanImpl, classMap /* this is a RuntimeBeanReference */)
```